# Extract and save specific user information. Reference in foreach

Tags: powershell, email, active-directory, exchange-server, alias

I'm looking for some help in automating alias creations on a new Exchange server on a new domain. This forms one of many steps of an ongoing migration.

I would like to run something like the following:

```
New-Mailbox -alias $Alias -name "$FullName" -database "CompanyDatabase" -org "CompanyMailboxes" -LinkedMasterAccount $UserAccount -LinkedDomainController domain.example.com -UserPrincipalName $UserEmailAddress
```

However, I need a way to extract the required variables from the existing domain and output them to a file. Then, by means of a foreach statement, recursively run the above command.

I need to extract each user's:

- Alias (`John Doe = johnd`)
- Full name
- Account (`johnd@domain.example.com` OR `john@domain.example.com`
  depending on when the user was created)
- Email address (`johnd@another.domain.com`)

Ideally I'd like to store the output in a file which I can use later if required.

Then somehow wrap the command above in a foreach and reference the file.

Comment: Shouldn't running `Get-Mailbox` on the source domain provide you with that information?

Comment: I don't think it can. Not all of the information anyway. I think Get-ADUser will? But I don't know how to extract the information I need in such a manner that I can reference it in my alias script inside a foreach. That's just murky.

Comment: @Ludicael : you think or you know? As far as I know Get-Mailbox should provide you with all this info. Of course, most if this info is also present in AD, but why make it hard on yourself?

Comment: Don't mean to make it hard for myself. Just find myself in a position where I don't really know what's going on, nor quite what is required exactly. I'm a UNIX administrator, not Windows... Powershell is totally unknown to me. Which is why I'm grateful for the help provided by people like yourself in this regard, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. To thank the respondents for their help, and to help others with the same issue:

Run the following powershell script on the domain controller.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
foreach ($User in (Get-ADUser -Server "<SERVER>" -Filter * -Properties EmailAddress)){Write-Output "$($User.SamAccountName),$($User.EmailAddress),$($User.Name)" >> 'C:\output.csv'}
```

The output will be saved as a CSV (without headings) to C:\output.csv

Copy the output file to your exchange server, and run the following script in the exchange console (you'll need to include your own headings in the CSV, I used "Name" and "Surname" etc. here, for example);

```
Import-CSV -delimiter ";" "output.csv" | Foreach {
$FullName = $_.Name + " " + $_.Surname
New-Mailbox -alias $_.Alias -name $Fullname -Firstname $_.Name -Lastname $_.Surname -database "<DATABASE>" -org "<OU>" -LinkedMasterAccount $_.AccountDomain -LinkedDomainController <DOMAIN CONTROLLER> -UserPrincipalName $_.Email
}
```

I was able to successfully create an alias for all users using this method. Your situation may vary, but I hope this is sufficient to reverse engineer, should such be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$OLD = Get-mailbox -resultsize 10
foreach ( $NEW in $OLD ) { New-Mailbox -alias $OLD.alias -name $OLD.Name ... }
```

That works in the simplest of ways, you'll want to tinker with it more as you'll pick up all manner of mailboxes this way.

EDIT : Are the existing attributes the same as they would be in the new domain?

```
-alias $( ( $OLD.Name ).Split( " " )[-1] + ( $OLD.Name ).Split( " " )[0] )
```

Then you could use the same command to do the email address?

```
$( ( $OLD.Name ).Split( " " )[-1] + ( $OLD.Name ).Split( " " )[0] + "@another.domain.com" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm having a gander now to see if I can adapt the first code block.

Comment: Currently there is a full trust implemented between the two domains. My employer is split into two companies, the old domain will exist for a few months within the other entity, it's their responsibility to complete the migration when necessary. The entity I work for is hosting the new domain. I need to ensure that the aliases are set up for each user on the old domain; on the new domain.

Comment: The attributes will be the same, I've managed to write an automated script which will handle the export and import of the old users when the time comes, as well as their mailboxes. So from my end all that's left is what this question is about. Thanks again though, I'm trying out your suggestion.